# Standalone jetty with Spring boot management endpoint on different port

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, spring-boot-actuator

I have a server running spring boot application 1.2.4 on standalone jetty 9.3.3  with spring boot management opened on port 7080 , accessible by `http://localhost:7080/manage/`.
Below is the relevant configuration from yml:

```
management:
  port: 7080
  contextPath: /manage
```

I'm trying to migrate to spring boot 1.3.8 on this standalone jetty, but spring boot no longer opens the management port on standalone servlet container - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3345.
Now, i really need to keep things as they were with my previous version having spring-boot management accessible the same way it was.

What would be the best practice here?

Thanks,